# TikZ: remove/override auto option (arrow label positioning) from a defined style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a defined style which I am applying to many arrows.  Most of the time, I want them to have label nodes positioned using `auto`, but occasionally I do not.  Currently, I simply add `auto` wherever necessary.  Since `auto` is the default, though, it would seem more natural to include it in the style; but if I do so, is there a way to occasionally turn it off?

Currently writing e.g.:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
          [myarrow/.style={->,font=\scriptsize}]
  \draw[myarrow,auto] (0,0) to node {L} (0,1);
  \draw[myarrow,auto] (1,0) to node {L} (1,1);
  \draw[myarrow,auto] (2,0) to node {L} (2,1);
  \draw[myarrow] (3,0) to node {M} (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Would prefer to write something like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
          [myarrow/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,auto}]
  \draw[myarrow] (0,0) to node {L} (0,1);
  \draw[myarrow] (1,0) to node {L} (1,1);
  \draw[myarrow] (2,0) to node {L} (2,1);
  \draw[myarrow,not auto] (3,0) to node {M} (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I don’t know what to put for `not auto`.

Comment: @percusse: OK, I fail on reading comprehension — I had looked over that section of the manual several times over and somehow missed this!  If you make that an answer, I’ll accept it.

Comment: No problem at all. The CVS version manual is 1052 pages ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The auto option is both an anchor selector and at the same time an on/off switch. That means you can both use `auto=<left,right>` and `auto=<true,false>`.

For the interested

```
\tikzoption{auto}[]{\csname tikz@install@auto@anchor@#1\endcsname}
```

is how it is defined. So whatever option is given replaces `#1` and providing `false` option or just using `auto` causes the following to be triggered.

```
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\tikz@auto@anchor@on}
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@false{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax}
```